# Unity. How do you access a scripts functions when you define it as a MonoBehaviour Variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do you access a scripts functions when you define it as a MonoBehaviour Variable...
(See big sample code below)
unity recognizes the script and attaches it so far so good.
but how do you access its functions... it this way..?

```
VariableItemSkript. ?????.UseItem(UserObj);   // <======== how do i access the script
```

I know that this works...:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<ScriptNameHere>().UseItem(UserObj);
```

But i have 300 + item scripts
and i don't want to reference a table each time a new item is generated...

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Items : MonoBehaviour
{
    //(unrelated variables)
    public MonoBehaviour VariableItemSkript;
    public GameObject UserObj; // set by inventory or NPC pickup Event. 

    public void Start()
    {
        // =================================================================================== // gets the item script on the item automatically
        var Skripts = GetComponents(typeof(MonoBehaviour)); // get all scripts on current object.
        foreach (MonoBehaviour Skript in Skripts)           //for each of them.
        {
            if (Skript != GetComponent<Item>())             //exclude the "item" handle (this) Script.
            {
                print(Skript.ToString());
                VariableItemSkript = Skript;  //set the script object so we can access it.
            }
        }
    }
    public void ItemUsage(GameObject UserObj) // triggered by active item use event (inventory or NPC use event)
    {
        if (VariableItemSkript != null)
        {
            VariableItemSkript. ?????.UseItem(UserObj);   // <======== how do i access the script
        }
        else Debug.Log("no item"); // it dosnt logg so it sees the item
    }
    //(unrelated 400+ lines of code)
}
```

Comment: Is there a parent class or interface that defines/declares `UseItem`? If so, what is it called?

Comment: this is just a sample code of one of the items that i have 
all items that i have make share the "public void UseItem(GameObject ObjPlayer)"
function i hope this answered your question...

```
    public void UseItem(GameObject ObjPlayer)
    {
        GameObject ShieldsFolder = Player.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
        ActiveShield = ShieldsFolder.transform.GetChild(ShieldType).gameObject;
        MaxMana = PlayerStats.playerStats.maxMana;
        Mana = PlayerStats.playerStats.mana;
        Difference = Mana / MaxMana;
        ShieldActive();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much a textbook use of interfaces.

1. Define an interface called `IUsableItem` and have it declare `UseItem` there:

   ```
   // IUsableItem.cs
   using UnityEngine;

   interface IUsableItem
   {
       void UseItem(Gameobject obj);
   }
   ```
2. Then, have each of your items that implement `UseItem`, implement the `IUsableItem` interface. For instance, you might have `Book` and `Bread` classes that might look like this:

   ```
   class Book : MonoBehaviour, IUsableItem
   {
       // ...
       void UseItem(Gameobject obj)
       {
           // ...
       }
       // ...    
   }
   ```

   ```
   class Bread : Food, IUsableItem // Food is a MonoBehaviour
   { 
       // ...
       void UseItem(Gameobject obj)
       {
           // ...
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Then in `Items`, you can just call it a `IUsableItem` instead of a `MonoBehaviour` (fields and local variable names typically begin with a lower case, so I have changed them accordingly):

   ```
   using UnityEngine;

   public class Items : MonoBehaviour
   {
       //(unrelated variables)
       public IUsableItem variableItemSkript;
       public GameObject userObj; // set by inventory or NPC pickup Event. 

       public void Start()
       {
           // gets the item script on the item automatically
           variableItemSkript = GetComponent<IUsableItem>();
           if (variableItemSkript != null) 
           {
               print(variableItemSkript.ToString());
           }
       }

       public void ItemUsage(GameObject UserObj) // triggered by active item use event (inventory or NPC use event)
       {
           if (variableItemSkript != null)
           {
               variableItemSkript.UseItem(UserObj);
           }
           else Debug.Log("no item"); // it dosnt logg so it sees the item
       }
       //(unrelated 400+ lines of code)
   }
   ```